# mysql use SHOW CREATE TABLE with dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to see the sql text from SHOW CREATE TABLE for any table for debugging purposes. Can I do that with prepared escaping?

```
// doesn't work because table name is escaped as string
 SHOW CREATE TABLE ?

//doesn't work, syntax is not allowed    
SHOW CREATE TABLE (SELECT table_name FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables`   WHERE  `TABLE_NAME`=?)
```

Comment: Just use the select from `information_schema` without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: *"Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth."* -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use prepared statement:

```
-- here goes your table name, could be parametrized to call from app
SET @tab_name = '`tab`';   

SET @query = REPLACE('SHOW CREATE TABLE @tab_name', '@tab_name', @tab_name);

-- SELECT @query;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6318e/12/4)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Table  ║                                                    Create Table                                                     ║
╠════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ tab    ║ CREATE TABLE `tab` ( `col1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `col2` datetime DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ║
╚════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

If you need it for every table you could wrap it with loop or cursor.

*Warning:*

*You should quote `@tab_name` in application layer to avoid SQL Injection.*